# How to change date appearance

Tags: php, date, format

I have this date: `24/11/1987` and I would like to change its appeareance to look like this:

`24 NOV`

I have seen the date format and there is a variable which allows to show the date the way I need but how can I change an existing date?

This is the example found on the internet:

`Textual month (and just the month) m   "March", "jun", "DEC"`

The `m` would be the variable needed in the function.

Thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php -1 because this is a RTFM question

Comment: Both your question and RTFM can be answered through a quick google search. Please note that even if it may sound harsh, that acronym is a common internet word and should be read with a light, non aggressive tone.

Comment: Sorry but you should know, Im from Spain and many of these terms may not even exist here or if they do they may be called differently or I just never heard of it :P.

Comment: I suspect that most developers worldwide have heard the RTFM acronym at one time or another.... if you haven't, the PHP Docs are available in [Spanish](http://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.formats.date.php) though admittedly not in Catalan, and I believe Google also exists in Spain

Comment: Sure thing, sorry about that, just thought that the purpose of this site is to help out (which you all do) but I see that the questions should be more specific and hard to find online I suppose. Will do next time!

Comment: Sorry for the -1 but with PHP Date Questions I'm pretty picky: Those have all been answered before (if not you've got the chance to win a 500 Reputation Bonus Bounty - just claim in the PHP Chatroom (Room 11)). Therefore it's required you do intensive search before asking any new PHP Date question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtotime` thinks that by using slashes, it's an American format (MM/DD/YYYY) rather than European format (DD/MM/YYYY).

```
$date = '24/11/1987';
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
echo date('d M', strtotime($date));
```

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.

http://php.net/strtotime

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
$date = str_replace('/', '-', "24/11/1987");
echo date("d M", strtotime($date))?>
```

You need to convert your date to `24-11-1987` since `/` will be considered as  American `m/d/y. For more details see [this](https://www.php.net/strtotime). For date function see [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$dateToConvert = new DateTime('24/11/1987');
echo $dateToConvert->format('d-M-Y');
```